# javafx button color not changing

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm doing a little connect4 game and I've started on the GUI. I made the piece class which creates the button for the piece and sets its color. But when I test it out in the GUI, the only thing that appears is the text, if there was no text(which was only used to check) the button is invisible

code for creating button

```
piece = new Button("testing");
piece.setShape(new Circle());
if (colour == 1) {
    piece.setStyle("fx-background-color: #DC143C");
} else {
    piece.setStyle("fx-background-color: #0000FF");
}
```

code for adding button

```
int col = piece.getCol();
Button button = piece.getPiece();
root.addColumn(col, button);
```

I have no skill at all with CSS and very little in JavaFX so I don't understand why it's not working

Comment: Instead of `"fx-background-color: #DC143C"` try `"-fx-background-color: #DC143C"`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: ok thanks it worked, i guess the tutorial i was using had a mistake in it